Why pandas apply is faster than vectorization
I knew vectorization faster thand apply in pandas.. but' below benchmarck says apply is faster than vectorization.. I confused about that, Am i using vectorization wrongly?
# making data
data = [' example text '] * 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['tr_content'])

# benchmark vectorization
start_time = time.time()
df['tr_content'] = df['tr_content'].str.strip()
df['tr_content'] = df['tr_content'].str[0].str.upper() + df['tr_content'].str[1:]
print("Method 1 execution time: ", time.time() - start_time)

# Recreate data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['tr_content'])

# benchmark apply
start_time = time.time()
capitalize_at_first = lambda x: (y := str(x).strip()) and y[0].upper() + y[1:]
df['tr_content'] = df['tr_content'].apply(capitalize_at_first)
print("Method 2 execution time: ", time.time() - start_time)


String operations are not vectorized like numeric ones. Vectorization in this case is essentially a wrapper around a for loop. For numeric operations, speed is improved by using a lower level data structure, string operations are still performed on python objects.

So faster like apply should be df['tr_content'] = [(y := str(x).strip()) and y[0].upper() + y[1:] for x in df['tr_content']] - list comprehension

String vectorisation for something like strip is just a for loop. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/58461fef2315d228d08f65f8a9430e9294d65b31/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L2850. Also, in your example the "vectorised" version loops over the data at least three times; the "apply" version does so only once. This is time-consuming.
